# In chrome, mouseenter event fires on <use> element when event defined on target, other events don't fire

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, mouseevent, href

I have a situation where an element *A* inside embeded SVG has a `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events defined. There is a separate `<use>` element referring to *A*. For some reason, in Chrome (and other chromium browsers) the `mouseenter` event gets fired on the `<use>` element while other evens, such as `mouseleave` or `click`, do not.

I believe that events should not follow `href` links, as the `<use>` element may have completely different meaning on the page.

Is there a good way to prevent this behavior?

I would like to avoid workarounds, such as cloning the element, instead of relying on `<use>`. In the particular application, the target element can be changed programmatically, allowing the changes to be reflected by the `<use>` element. Also, it allows the `<use>` element to be redirected, and thus display, different elements in the interface.

Here is a simple example demonstrating the problem:

```js
let circle = document.getElementById("circ");

    circle.addEventListener("mouseenter",()=>{ //fires on use
        circle.setAttribute("fill", "red")
    });

    circle.addEventListener("mouseleave",()=>{ //does not fire
        circle.setAttribute("fill", "black")
    });

   circle.addEventListener("click",()=>{ //does not fire
        circle.setAttribute("fill", "green")
    });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>GUI</title>
</head>

<body style="">
<div id="gui">

<svg height="500" version="1.1" width="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <ellipse cx="100" cy="100" rx="50" ry="50" id="circ"></ellipse>
  <use href="#circ" x="200"></use>
</svg>

</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Probably a bug - use elements shouldn't inherit any events from their reference definition/symbol. Not sure, but maybe should attach your events rather to the use elements. See this [example codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/oNQzVeB). The base ellipse is wrapped in a `<defs>` elements. So you can either toggle colors for each `<use>` instance or change the referenced ellipse - also changing the use elements appearance.

Comment: I will submit a bug report. I was hoping that there was an obscure setting I have missed that stopped such events.  In my application, I ended up disabling pointer events to the given problematic elements, and moving them to background transparent rectangles.

Comment: If you file a bug report with Chrome, please post the link here afterwards. So future readers can track the bug. Thanks!

Comment: The bug report is here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1457602

Answer (score 0):

There is only one element that has the ID `circ` and that is the element that you add the event listener to. On top of that the following applies to the `use` element:

> However, these cloned element instances remain linked to the referenced source and reflect DOM mutations in the original. In addition, all style rules that apply in the scope of the referenced element also apply in the scope of the cloned shadow tree. [Document Structure — SVG 2](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/struct.html#UseElement)

So, the `use` element reflects what happens to the original element. You need to listen for events on the use elements. I prefer adding the event listener to a parent element -- here the SVG itself and then test what element the event is happening on. Use `onmouseout` instead of `mouseleave`.

```js
let svg01 = document.getElementById("svg01");

svg01.addEventListener("mouseenter", e => {
  if(e.target.nodeName == "use"){
    e.target.setAttribute("fill", "red");
  }
}, true);

svg01.addEventListener("mouseout", e => {
  if(e.target.nodeName == "use"){
    e.target.setAttribute("fill", "black");
  }
});

svg01.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if(e.target.nodeName == "use"){
    e.target.setAttribute("fill", "orange");
  }
});
```

```html
<svg id="svg01" height="500" version="1.1" width="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <ellipse cx="100" cy="100" rx="50" ry="50" id="circ"></ellipse>
  </defs>
  <use href="#circ" x="0"></use>
  <use href="#circ" x="200"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: In light of the inconsistent behavior of browsers that the sample code demonstrates, it is probably not a good idea to listen to events on linked elements. Hopefully, the inconsistency will be resolved eventually. I believe that pointer interactions should not be considered part of the style of the element, and should not be passed along the links.

Comment: I don't see how my example/solution is inconsistent between browsers. Can explain how they are inconsistent?

Comment: No, i mean the original example i provided in the question. Your example doesn't have the problem.